# Eclipse CDT gdb No source file named

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I have the following Eclipse CDT setup on a Red Hat Linux system:

- Eclipse Mars with CDT 8.7
- gdb 7.6

I have two projects open in my workspace

- Project1: the main source code that builds the executable I want to debug
- Project2: library code that gets statically linked with the binary in Project1

Project2 is linked to Project1 in its properties.

The problem occurs when I try to set breakpoints in a debug session in source files that are in Project2. `gdb` reports the following error:

```
No source file named <absolute_path_to_file>.
```

The weird thing is that I can set breakpoints in the `gdb` console in Eclipse using the function name and/or function name and line number syntax. When I do this, `gdb` reports that it successfully set the breakpoint showing the file and line number. The file name, in the trace message, has no path (maybe relevant?)

Using `objdump` I was able to confirm that my executable has all of the symbols and files in it (not absolute paths though... relevant?)

Once I get the debugger to stop at the breakpoint after setting it using the function name, I can then add/remove breakpoints within the Debug perspective like normal; even if I restart the debugging session.

I've seen lots of comments about loading shared libraries into `gdb`, but the code I'm trying to break into is in a statically linked library, not a shared one.

Given that I can add breakpoints using the normal method once I get `gdb` to break on one added manually in the conosole, indicates to me that maybe something is missing in my `gdb` settings.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like eclipse bug. Check gdb-traces console to see how gdb responds, when eclipse tries to set a breakpoint.

Comment: I believe you are hitting an Eclipse-CDT bug here. Significant improvements have been made to this part of the code base as part of [Bug 472765](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472765). This will be part of the next Eclipse release in just over a month's time. But if you had time to test it against your case and it still wasn't working I have a chance to fix the issues ahead of the release. [Linux 64-bit download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/M7/eclipse-cpp-neon-M7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

Comment: @JonahGraham I'll try to test the new release you've linked to and will report back. Thanks!

Comment: @JonahGraham I was able to test the version of Eclipse in your link, but unfortunately the same problems exist there.

Comment: @unluddite Thank you for that. Would you be willing to work with me for a bit so I can recreate your test case so that I can fix it? In the first instance I need the GDB MI Traces. You can get that by changing to the "gdb traces" console in the Eclipse Console View.

Comment: You can email me if that is easier too jonah at kichwacoders dot com